# Disable Click-drag scrolling in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

The smooth scrolling and Android-style scrolling is great, but how do I keep Ubuntu from scrolling when I try to click and drag to select text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed, after the system updates awhile ago... Thanks to whoever fixed this bug :)

Comment: You can accept this answer that you've posted. (You only have to wait 2 days to accept an answer to your own question after posting it. BTW, after accepting it please feel free to flag this comment as obsolete.)